# Extracting files nested within a zip file using System.IO.Compression C#

Tags: c#

I have a number of zip files that contain .txt files nested in sub directories within the zip file. I am trying to extract the .txt files and output them to another directory, however I am getting an error 'Could not find a part of the path...' This error occurs at the 'entry.FullName' point

I believe I need to remove the file path at some stage of the unzip process since I can get the code to run if I use zip files with .txt files in them without any sub-directories. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var zp in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\\My Documents\\DMU\\Frontrunner2015\\ZipIn\\", "*.zip"))
        {
            string zipPath = zp;
            string extractPath = @"D:\\My Documents\\DMU\\Frontrunner2015\\ZipOut\\";

            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));
                    }
                    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(extractPath))
                    {.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have helped if you left the path in the error message there so people could see what path was not found. I would guess that when you combine extractPath and FullName you end up with a folder name that does not exist - as you mentioned the files in the zip file have subdirectories.

I think you really meant to use `Name` property in your `Path.Combine` call.

Comment: You are absolutely right! This worked perfectly and makes perfect sense :) Much appreciated.